# VB.NET Network Database

Tags: vb.net

What concepts/steps shall i need to learn to access a central database(server). The system will have a software(manipulate by users) which access the database in the server. System like inventory systems, billing, etc..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know vb/C#.net (which I assume you know). Next you must be able to write SQL queries, stored procs, T-sql, etc. to communicate to the database. Finally you need to know ADO.net to communicate between your application and database.

You can start your ADO.net study from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx
http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_database/adonet/article.php/c15033

Here is a link which will help you under stand the data access layer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx

Hope this helps...!!!